# Getting Usable data from deserialized JSON data using ColdFusion

Tags: parsing, struct, coldfusion, json-deserialization, coldfusion-11

I have successfully deserialized my JSON data into a structure, however, it appears to be a multilayered structure with an array inside of it.  How do I get the data where the arrows are in the image into a usable variable?

I have already tried several ways to try and get the data but get various error messages. Our current solution isn't multi-layered like this so this type of variable works, but not with this new response.

The image is dumping this variable:

```
<cfset responseStruct = deserializeJSON(response.Filecontent)>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your tenders array  always 1 or more than 1 or some is empty ?

Comment: Should always be 1.  We only have 1 charge at a time.

Comment: Could you please post your Json data here ? If possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to

```
responseStruct.transaction.tenders[1].amount_money.amount;
responseStruct.transaction.tenders[1].card_details.card.card_brand;
responseStruct.transaction.tenders[1].card_details.card.last_4;
responseStruct.transaction.tenders[1].card_details.status;
responseStruct.transaction.tenders[1].transaction_id;
```

Comment: James, I swear I tried this and it didn't work. I must have done something slightly different but this WORKS!  Thx.